# Apache 2.4: owncloud in sub-directory outside of DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.4, directory, documentroot, owncloud

I am working on moving current setup of owncloud from sub-domain `https://cloud.example.com` to sub-directory `https://example.com/cloud` to make all my apps covered by one SSL certificate. The problem is that owncloud makes redirect to login page, but Apache makes it within virtual host's DocumentRoot. Alias **/cloud** doesn't work - every request from /cloud fall to the main site. And PHP-FPM 7.3.33 throws error "Got error 'Primary script unknown'".

So, my httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /cloud /var/www/owncloud
    <Directory /var/www/owncloud>
        SSLRequireSSL
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
        </IfModule>

        SetEnv HOME /var/www/owncloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/owncloud
        SetEnv MOD_X_SENDFILE_ENABLED 1

        XSendFile On
        XSendFilePath /var/tmp
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

/var/www/owncloud/config/config.php:

```
  'trusted_domains' => 
      array (
        0 => 'locahost',
        1 => 'example.com',
      ),
  'datadirectory' => '/var/lib/owncloud',
  'overwrite.cli.url' => 'https://example.com/cloud',
  'overwritewebroot' => '/cloud',
```

How can I achieve that?

Thank you.

Comment: Since you have a `AllowOverride All` check if there are `.htaccess` files that do unexpected rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to set RewriteBase in OWNCLOUD_HOME/.htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /cloud
```

Everything works as expected now.